# Display commiter date in gitk instead of author date

Tags: git, gitk

I am using **gitk** to browse my git repo and i would like to print the commit date of commit instead of author date in **gitk** (on the third column).

Can you tell me how to do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify gitk.  (It's a big TCL script, so it is easy to modify.)

If you look at a recent version of gitk, you will find:

```
proc drawcmittext {id row col} {
```

near line 6100.  About 72 or so lines in you will find:

```
    set date [lindex $commitinfo($id) 2]
    set date [formatdate $date]
```

There is no further code to change `date`, so from here on you are stuck with whatever `formatdate` did to the initial value from the `lindex` expression (list index).

The `$commitinfo` (associative array based on looking up the commit ID) fields are:

```
    set commitinfo($id) [list $headline $auname $audate \
                             $comname $comdate $comment $hasnote $diff]
```

(last two lines of `parsecommit`, around line 1730).  So index 2 is `$audate`, which is the parsed author-date.  The committer-date is from index 4 (indices 1 and 3 being author and committer respectively).

The obvious change would be to select index 4 if some command line switch were used.  (Making a Tk button that changes the value dynamically would be possible as well, but harder.)

Comment: nice I didn't know that gitk is a script.. And i alsi replace 1 by 3 to have the commiter name

Answer (score 2):

torek's solution as patch for gitk 1.8.1.4-1.1.1 to display committer date instead of author date:

```
--- /usr/bin/gitk       2013-02-26 15:44:18.000000000 +0100
+++ /usr/local/bin/gitk 2017-09-14 13:52:13.629947026 +0200
@@ -5963,7 +5963,7 @@
     }
     set headline [lindex $commitinfo($id) 0]
     set name [lindex $commitinfo($id) 1]
-    set date [lindex $commitinfo($id) 2]
+    set date [lindex $commitinfo($id) 4]
     set date [formatdate $date]
     set font mainfont
     set nfont mainfont
```

Save this patch in `gitk.patch` and apply:

```
cp /usr/bin/gitk .
patch -p0 gitk gitk.patch
sudo mv gitk /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Thx for the patch but you need to patch also the name field by replacing 1 by 3 as stated before

Comment: @user43968 Well in my case, I really want to replace only the committer date. We switched to Gerrit code review and chose to rebase commits by default. Often I am interested when a commit has been added to the devel or main branch (e.g.: why did the integration tests brake yesterday at 17:23? which changes have been done?), but I am never interested in the comitter (who cares who hit the submit button? the author is the expert behind the commit).

Answer (score -1):

Use this to display the commit date

```
git show -s --format=%ci <commit>
```

Check manual page for other formats of date string